# Snackbar is not visible (not rendered), but interactive (clickable)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm developing app with Xamarin and Monogame. Needed to show Snackbar, but it is not visible (not rendered), but interactive (clickable).
Basic usage:

```
Snackbar.Make(Window.DecorView.RootView, "Sync completed", Snackbar.LengthLong).Show()`.
```

Code executing in event handler which called on Google Play Game Services connected.
Activity layout creating using View from Monogame Game instance:

```
var g = new MainClass();
SetContentView(g.Services.GetService<View>());
g.Run();`
```

I have determine that:

1. Snackbar is rendered (visible) if it was created in OnCreate method.
2. Snackbar is rendered (visible) after an activity was suspended and restarted (for example if I've navigated to another activity or to another app):
   [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWHav.jpg)
3. Monogame does not handle touches in rectangle bounding snackbar:
   [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12uez.png)

Comment: Please add any relevant code to the question such as your call to create and show the snackbar and the context it's being called.

Comment: Basic usage: `Snackbar.Make(Window.DecorView.RootView, "Sync completed", Snackbar.LengthLong).Show ();`. Code executed in event handler which called on Google Play Game Services connected.

Comment: Please put this in your original post, not the comments :)